# Offload App remove what in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, offloading, ios11

I just installed iOS 11 beta and I noticed that Offload App, By offloading app what will be remove **Shared Directory** or **User Default** or remove both or other than this ?

[image]
Looking for suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Offloading lets you **”offload”** the bundle **(.ipa)** for your app to save disk space. It will delete the ipa file (which contains your libraries and resources) and store only Documents and Data that includes shared data, UserDefaults etc..

[image: Offload]

Once we offload the app, what remains is the app icon of it with a small download pip on it to indicate that it has been offloaded .

[image: Offloaded app]

Just by simple tapping on it, the app will get downloaded from the store and the saved Documents and Data will be integrated to the downloaded app, instead of an empty directory as it normally would with a fresh install.

[image: Installing offloaded app]

This is a really great feature by Apple especially for devices with just 16GB storage. As you can see offloading the Prisma app saves me 44MB which is great. And even more, iOS can automatically offloads unused apps for us.

[image: Auto offload]

Answer (score 1):

There is no official document(technical) available for `offloading apps` till the date but as the description(in setting app) says that `your documents and data will be saved` then I think it will save `user defaults , document directories and core data` - I mean all kind of data that can be stored!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will save Shared Directory & User Defaults. Everything else will be deleted.

Comment: documents and data - that means it will store all kind of data that is in directory i think!

Comment: @Lion Can't say for sure as official documentation is unavailable. But yes, it makes sense to not to delete data in shared directory, user defaults or documents directory.

Comment: can we get this feature enable or disable in xcode 9?